# OS update not working

Tags: updates

1 component with updates:
 • teamviewer Remote control and meeting solution. Version: 15.5.3

This is the update my OS is attempting. When I attempt to update it just finishes right away and the OS says I still have an update to complete. any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it

sudo apt-get upgrade

silly me, should have done this first.